# R computing not so fast

Tags: r

I have csv data in format Price,Volume

```
Price,Volume
329.237000000000,0.011000000000
329.500000000000,1.989000000000
328.006000000000,0.032000000000
328.447000000000,0.010100000000
328.448000000000,0.201455000000
327.839000000000,0.011188600000
328.006000000000,0.064333000000
327.930000000000,0.020800000000
328.006000000000,0.064333000000
327.918000000000,0.011139500000
327.869000000000,0.011090600000
328.127000000000,0.033460100000
....
```

moreover 16M rows.

What I wanted to do is to group that prices and amounts by price based volume OHLCV ticks, 100 000 USD each tick.
it took 200seconds to group 16000 rows so it's really slow...

i'm using while loop but i have no idea how can i get rid of it

output should be something like this

```
open    high    low close   volume (USD)
1   329.237 329.500 329.237 329.500 100.00000
2   329.500 329.500 329.500 329.500 100.00000
3   329.500 329.500 329.500 329.500 100.00000
4   329.500 329.500 329.500 329.500 100.00000
5   329.500 329.500 329.500 329.500 100.00000
6   329.500 329.500 329.500 329.500 100.00000
7   328.006 328.448 328.006 328.448 100.00000
8   328.448 328.127 328.448 328.127 100.00000
9   328.127 327.695 328.127 327.695 100.00000
10  327.695 327.695 327.695 327.695 100.00000
11  327.695 327.695 327.695 327.695 100.00000
```

Code:

```
library(data.table)

# choose file
#dti <- fread(file.choose())
dti <- fread("test2.csv")

names(dti)[1]<-"Price"
names(dti)[2]<-"Volume"


# rows count
irows <- nrow(dti)

# volume in 
vol_btc <- sum(dti$Volume)
vol_usd <- sum(dti$Price*dti$Volume)

# equals bars, 100000USD each
vol_range <- 100000
bc <- ceiling ( vol_usd / vol_range ) 

dto <- data.table ( open = numeric(bc),
                   high = numeric(bc),
                   low = numeric(bc),
                   close = numeric(bc),
                   volume = numeric(bc))

i <- 1
j <- 1

while ( i <= irows )
{
  pri <- dti$Price[i]
  vol <- dti$Volume[i]
  volu <- pri * vol


  if ( dto$open[j] == 0 ) { # new OHLCV bars

    dto$open[j] <- pri
    dto$high[j] <- pri
    dto$low[j]  <- pri

  } else {

    if (dto$high[j] < pri)
      dto$high[j] <- pri

    if (dto$low[j] > pri)
      dto$high[j] <- pri

  }

  dto$close[j] <- pri


  volc <- dto$volume[j] + volu - vol_range 

  if ( volc < 0 ) {
    dto$volume[j] <- dto$volume[j] + volu
  } else {

    dto$volume[j] = vol_range  
    j<-j+1

    if ( volc > 0 ){

      dto$open[j] <- pri
      dto$high[j] <- pri
      dto$low[j]  <- pri
      dto$close[j] <- pri

      if (volc > vol_range){

        dto$volume[j] <- vol_range

        k = floor ( volc / vol_range )

        if (k > 0) {

          dto[(j+1):(j+k-1)] <- dto[j]
          volc <- volc - vol_range * k
          j <- j + k

        }
      }

      dto$volume[j] <- volc

    } 

  } 


  i<-i+1
}
```

Comment: Can you put your script here, I cannot access your URL.

Comment: added code snippet thanks to Simon Verhoeven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't quite right, but maybe gives some indication of how to make this type of operation faster. Here's the data

```
url <- "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hsGACr2L"
dfi <- read.csv(url)
```

I calculate the product and cumulative sum of the product of price and volume. The calculation is vectorized so fast.

```
pv <- with(dfi, Price * Volume)
cpv <- cumsum(pv)
vol_range <- 100000
```

My strategy was to figure out how to group the data in a relatively efficient way. I did this by creating a logical vector that will have 'TRUE' when a new group starts (I think the actual calculation is wrong below, and that there are edge cases that will fail; probably the strategy needs to be re-thought, but the notion is to minimize the non-vectorized data modification)

```
grp <- logical(nrow(dfi))
i <- 1
repeat {
    grp[i] <- TRUE
    ## find first index evaluating to 'TRUE'
    i <- which.max(cpv - (cpv[i] - pv[i]) > vol_range)
    ## prevent fails when, e.g., any(diff(cvp) > vol_range)
    if (i > 1L && grp[i] == TRUE)
        i <- i + 1L
    if (i == 1L)   # no TRUE values, so FALSE is max, and elt 1 is first FALSE
        break
}
```

`cumsum(grp)` divides the data into the first, second, ... groups, and I add this to the data frame

```
dfi$Group <- cumsum(grp)
```

For the output, the basic strategy is to split Price (etc.) by Group, and apply a function to each group. There are a number of ways to do this, `tapply` is not particularly efficient (data.table excels at these types of calculations, but does not provide any particular benefit up to this point) but for the scale of data is likely to be sufficient.

```
dfo <- with(dfi, {
    data.frame(
        open = tapply(Price, Group, function(x) x[1]),
        high = tapply(Price, Group, max),
        low = tapply(Price, Group, max),
        close = tapply(Price, Group, function(x) x[length(x)]),
        volume = tapply(Volume, Group, sum),
        pv = tapply(Price * Volume, Group, sum))
})
```

This takes a fraction of a second for the 10,000 row sample data.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step of optimization, here my script:

```
    dti <- fread("test1.csv")
    dti[,VolUSD:=Volume*Price]
    # volume in
    vol_btc <- sum(dti$Volume)
    vol_usd <- sum(dti$VolUSD)
    vol_range <- 100
    bc <- ceiling ( vol_usd / vol_range )
    dto <- data.table ( open = numeric(bc),
                        high = numeric(bc),
                        low = numeric(bc),
                        close = numeric(bc),
                        volume = numeric(bc))

    j <- 1
    for (i in 1:nrow(dti))
    {
            pri <- dti$Price[i]
            vol <- dti$Volume[i]
            volu <- dti$VolUSD[i]


            if ( dto$open[j] == 0 ) { # otwieramy nowy slupe
                    dto$open[j] <- pri
                    dto$high[j] <- pri
                    dto$low[j]  <- pri
            } else {
                    dto$high[j]<-max(dto$high[j], pri)
                    dto$low[j]<-min(dto$low[j], pri)
            }
            dto$close[j] <- pri


            volc <- {dto$volume[j] + volu - vol_range}

            if ( volc < 0 ) {
                    dto$volume[j] <- {dto$volume[j] + volu}
            } else {
                    dto$volume[j] = vol_range
                    j<-j+1

                    if ( volc > 0 ){

                            dto$open[j] <- pri
                            dto$high[j] <- pri
                            dto$low[j]  <- pri
                            dto$close[j] <- pri

                            if (volc > vol_range){

                                    dto$volume[j] <- vol_range

                                    k = floor ( {volc / vol_range} )

                                    if (k > 0) {

                                            dto[{j+1}:{j+k-1}] <- dto[j]
                                            volc <- {volc - vol_range * k}
                                            j <- {j + k}

                                    }
                            }

                            dto$volume[j] <- volc

                    }
            }
    }
```

I change the vol_range to 100 because the total volume in the csv was less than 100000 USD.
It runs 33% faster (1.34 -> 0.91).
Change list:

1. bug at: if (dto$**low**[j] > pri) dto$**high**[j] <- pri
2. use of min/max rather than if
3. pre compute column vol_usd
4. remove the inc function

Comment: Large parts of this could be vectorized which would result in a speed-up by orders of magnitude.

Comment: thanks @ABA for help. Roland - I just started learning R and still I'm far far away from vector programming thinking ;)

Answer (score 0):

ok i tested both 100 and 100000 ranges, and test max/min vs if statement. Input data I pasted here (10K lines): http://pastebin.com/hsGACr2L

First i tested min/max:

```
dto$high[j]<-max(dto$high[j], pri)
dto$low[j]<-min(dto$low[j], pri)
```

result for 100USD range:

```
system.time(source("test.r"))
użytkownik     system   upłynęło
225.50       0.05     227.75
```

result 100000USD range:

```
system.time(source("test.r"))
użytkownik     system   upłynęło 
59.93       0.02      60.99
```

Then I tried if statement:

```
if (dto$high[j] < pri)
    dto$high[j] <- pri

if (dto$low[j] > pri)
    dto$low[j] <- pri
```

result for 100USD range:

```
> system.time(source("test.r"))
użytkownik     system   upłynęło 
186.36       0.08     191.27
```

result for 100000USD range:

```
> system.time(source("test.r"))
użytkownik     system   upłynęło 
 40.48       0.00      40.89
```

and I'm confused with this results...

tested code (improved by ABA):

```
library(data.table)

# choose file
#dti <- fread(file.choose())
dti <- fread("test.csv")

#names(dti)[1]<-"Price"
#names(dti)[2]<-"Volume"
dti[,VolUSD:=Volume*Price]


# rows count
irows <- nrow(dti)

# volume in 
vol_btc <- sum(dti$Volume)
vol_usd <- sum(dti$VolUSD)

# equals bars, 100000USD each
vol_range <- 100
bc <- ceiling ( vol_usd / vol_range ) 

dto <- data.table ( open = numeric(bc),
                   high = numeric(bc),
                   low = numeric(bc),
                   close = numeric(bc),
                   volume = numeric(bc))

i <- 1
j <- 1

while ( i <= irows )
{
  pri <- dti$Price[i]
# vol <- dti$Volume[i]
  volu <- dti$VolUSD[i]


  if ( dto$open[j] == 0 ) { # new OHLCV tick

    dto$open[j] <- pri
    dto$high[j] <- pri
    dto$low[j]  <- pri

  } else {

    dto$high[j]<-max(dto$high[j], pri)
    dto$low[j]<-min(dto$low[j], pri)
#   if (dto$high[j] < pri)
#       dto$high[j] <- pri
#   if (dto$low[j] > pri)
#       dto$low[j] <- pri
  }

  dto$close[j] <- pri


  volc <- dto$volume[j] + volu - vol_range 

  if ( volc < 0 ) {
    dto$volume[j] <- dto$volume[j] + volu
  } else {

    dto$volume[j] = vol_range  
    j<-j+1

    if ( volc > 0 ){

      dto$open[j] <- pri
      dto$high[j] <- pri
      dto$low[j]  <- pri
      dto$close[j] <- pri

      if (volc > vol_range){

        dto$volume[j] <- vol_range

        k = floor ( volc / vol_range )

        if (k > 0) {

          dto[(j+1):(j+k-1)] <- dto[j]
          volc <- volc - vol_range * k
          j <- j + k

        }
      }

      dto$volume[j] <- volc

    } 

  } 


  i<-i+1
}
```